# delete without a head pointer

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Question:
You are given a certain node somewhere in the middle of the linked list and you need to delete that node.
You are not given the head node to the linked list.
Condition: the given node has atleast one node next to it.

The structure of the node:

```
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
  Node(int x) {
    data = x;
    next = NULL;
  }
}*head;
```

My solution:

```
Node* temp=node->next;
node->data=node->next->data;
node->next=node->next->next;
delete temp;
```

Another solution(that i didn't understand):

```
Node *temp = node->next;
*node = *(node->next);
delete temp;
```

Both give correct results but **i did not understand the 2nd line of the latter solution.**

Comment: Your solution copies the values from the `next` node to the current node and `delete`s the next `node`. Your solution will fail, however, if `node->next` is `NULL`, since `node->next->data` and `node->next->next` would be Undefined Behaviour.

The other solution works in a similar way, but uses the `operator=` to overwrite the values on the current `node`. It will also fail if `node->next` is `NULL`, since `delete`ing a `nullptr` is also UB.

You aren't actually asking a question though...

Comment: @ChrisMM Deleting a null pointer is a no-op.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, you're right, I always forget that one.

Comment: Presumably there is an additional constraint that the node to delete cannot be the tail node, because you can't delete that one without being able to clear the "next" pointer of the prior node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct `Node` has a default copy assignment since neither it nor a move assignment is declared.

So `*node = *(node->next);` copies both attributes (`data` and `next`) from `*(node->next)` to `*node` making it exactly the same as:

```
(*node).data = (*(node->next)).data
(*node).next = (*(node->next)).next
```

Answer (score 1):

The second solution is the same as the first, except it uses the assignment operator of the class instead of assigning the members separately.

> so you mean in the 2nd solution too the data member gets copied(like in the 1st one)?

Yes, that is what the copy assignment operator of the class does.

> see don't understand this line.. *node = *(node->next); so can you elaborate/explain this line.

`*node` indirects through the pointer `node` which points to an object of type `Node`. The result is an lvalue to `Node`.

`*(node->next)` first indirects through the pointer `node` to access its member `next` which is pointer to another object of type `Node`. This other pointer is also indirected through, which results in lvalue to another `Node`.

Finally, the assignment operator assigns the first `Node` to the other `Node`. The copy assignment operator of the class copies each member from the right hand operand to the corresponding member of the left hand operand.

Comment: so you mean in the 2nd solution too the data member gets copied(like in the 1st one)?

see don't understand this line..
*node = *(node->next);

so can you elaborate/explain this line.